# Drupal blocks not showing up

Tags: blocks

I am editing a site someone else built for my small nonprofit organization, and as you will see, I know very little about working with drupal (or anything beyond basic HTML, really.) I apologize in advance for that and will be so appreciative if anyone can help me.

I am trying to fix a problem. I am trying to add a listed page to a block, and the block is now not showing up on any pages it was previously associated with. When I went into a different block and tried to add a page, that block also stopped showing up. (You can see an example here: http://africaid.com/upcomingevents -- the left hand side block has disappeared.)

I am wondering if the problem is related to two warning messages. The first, on the "Administer" home page, says "One or more problems were detected with your Drupal installation. Check the status report for more information."

When I go to list content, I get the following message:

```
strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/views.module on line 843.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_display::options_validate() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_validate(&$form, &$form_state) in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_display.inc on line 1877.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_display_page::options_submit() should be compatible with views_plugin_display::options_submit(&$form, &$form_state) in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_display_page.inc on line 481.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_field_broken::ui_name() should be compatible with views_handler::ui_name($short = false) in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field.inc on line 641.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_field_user::init() should be compatible with views_handler_field::init(&$view, $options) in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/modules/user/views_handler_field_user.inc on line 48.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_sort_broken::ui_name() should be compatible with views_handler::ui_name($short = false) in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_sort.inc on line 82.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_validate() should be compatible with views_handler::options_validate($form, &$form_state) in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter.inc on line 585.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_submit() should be compatible with views_handler::options_submit($form, &$form_state) in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter.inc on line 585.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter_broken::ui_name() should be compatible with views_handler::ui_name($short = false) in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter.inc on line 609.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter_boolean_operator::value_validate() should be compatible with views_handler_filter::value_validate($form, &$form_state) in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter_boolean_operator.inc on line 128.
strict warning: Declaration of views_bulk_operations_plugin_style::options() should be compatible with views_object::options() in /home/africaid/public_html/sites/all/modules/views_bulk_operations/views_bulk_operations_plugin_style.inc on line 280.
```

If anybody can help me with this, I will be grateful for eternity.

Thank you,
Ashley

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a few assumptions, the main one being that you're using Drupal 6...

Basically your PHP [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) settings include `E_STRICT` compliance, and the code in the version of Views you've got installed isn't compatible with it. D6, and subsequently the associated version of Views, was written for PHP4 and PHP5, and as such isn't compatible with `E_STRICT`.

You can either

- Disable `E_STRICT` error reporting in your php.ini/other php conf file (if you're not sure how to do this, get whoever administers your server to do it - it'll make sense to them). Or
- Apply the patch in [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/465332) (comment #11) which will remove the problems for PHP5.3. If you have PHP5.4 installed, there's another patch in #26 to apply too.

Comment: Hi Clive, thank you so much for this answer and for trying to help. I'm the only one left to help with the site -- our original drupal programmer is gone. Is what you suggest above something an amateur (i.e. me) can do? It looks like it is Drupal 6.20. I check the "status report" and it said I haven't run a cron job in awhile. Might that be the problem? Is there a risk in manually running a cron job?

Comment: it not related to cron, you can run cron manually at anytime.

Comment: No risk in running cron, no...as for fixing it, you're probably going to need at least a bit of technical knowledge to use either of those methods. Unless you're confident of being able to back yourself out of anything that may go wrong I wouldn't attempt it. Patching would be the easier choice if you're unfamiliar with either I think

Comment: Thank you so much, Clive and Bala. Do you have any recommendations about where to find individuals familiar with Drupal who might be willing/able to help execute what you recommend above?